# Camel Multicast issue

Tags: apache-camel

We are using the below configuration to send a file from single source to multiple remote destinations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

        <routeContext id="gcgRatesOutbound" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
                <route id="gcgRatesFileOut">       
                        <from uri="file:{{nas.root}}/{{gcg.out.prices.dir}}?delay={{poll.delay}}&amp;initialDelay={{initial.delay}}&amp;readLock=rename&amp;scheduledExecutorService=#scheduledExecutorService" />                                       
                        <multicast stopOnException="true">

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client1_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client1}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client2_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client2}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />                               

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client3_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client3}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />                                               
                        </multicast> 
                </route>
        </routeContext>
</beans>
```

Using the above confirguration the file reaches the remote destinations, which confirmed that the connection to all the remote destinations were successfull.

We need that the file should be moved to the archive folder after the file has been successfully transfered to all the remote destinations.
And should move to error folder incase of any error.

However, when I add the archival code ( element) as child  element to the multicast element in the above configuration and use the  and the  tag to move the file to error folder incase of an error. The file does not reach the remote destinations.

```
<doTry>       
        <multicast stopOnException="true" parallelProcessing="true">

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client1_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client1}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client2_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client2}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />                               

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client3_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client3}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />

                <to uri="file://{{nas.root}}/{{gcg.out.prices.dir}}?fileName={{archive.dir}}" />
        </multicast> 
<doCatch>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>                                       

                <to uri="file://{{nas.root}}/{{gcg.out.prices.dir}}?fileName={{error.dir}}" />
</doCatch>
</doTry>
```

The file does not reach the remote destinations nor does it produce any log  and the file is moved to archive folder.

I tried placing the remote destinations, the archival code and the move to error code in seperate routes and have its reference in a single multicast as below

```
            <to uri="direct:Client1FileOut" />

            <to uri="direct:Client2FileOut" />                                                                                                                       

            <to uri="direct:Client3FileOut" />                       

            <to uri="direct:MoveToArchive" />
```

```
<route id="gcgFileOut1">       
                        <from uri="direct:Client1FileOut" />                       
                        <doTry>                       

                                <to uri="scp://{{gcg.ste.Client1_User_Name}}@{{gcg.ste.Host_Name}}:{{gcg.ste.Port_Number}}/{{gcg.ste.Destination_Client1}}?knownHostsFile={{ssh.knownHosts}}&amp;privateKeyFile={{ssh.privateKey}}" />
                                <doCatch>
                                                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                                                <handled>
                                                        <constant>true</constant>
                                                </handled>

                                                <to uri="direct:gcgError" />       

                                </doCatch>
                        </doTry>
                </route>
```

However, The file does not reach the remote destinations nor does it produce any log  and the file is moved to archive folder.

I am new to camel.

I tried using the shareUnitOfWork attribute as below

```
<multicast shareUnitOfWork="true">
```

However, the file moved to archive folder along with Test_2_19082013_3.txt.camelLock file

Not sure why this file is also moved to archive when the file dropped was Test_2_19082013_3.txt

Also there is folder named "ARCHIV~1" created in the drop location.

Comment: This has also been discussed first on the Camel mailing list. The reporter didnt care to mention that :(

Comment: Claus, I suppose I am here since the reply there did not help and I am still waiting in the middle of an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Something might went wrong when moving the file to archive. You have `stopOnException="true" parallelProcessing="true"` and the local file is probably done first as it should be the fastest.

You probably want to print the error somewhere. Now, you catch the exception and mark the error as handled. Still you expect logs. Use the [log](http://camel.apache.org/log) component and output some log statements manually. Not only in case or error but also in case of success. You can log in the debug level so that you can manually enable log outprint in case you need it - like now.

Another option for you to figure out what's going on is to enable [trace](http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) which will make you less "blind".

That said about debugging on your own  -

You are archiving and storeing error messages in the input directory. The lock file you see is when Camel is reading. This is likely what's casuing your application to malfunction.

`{{nas.root}}/{{gcg.out.prices.dir}}`

The `fileName=...` is the filename, not another sub directory.

So: `file://{{nas.root}}/{{gcg.out.prices.dir}}/{{archive.dir}}` should do it (likewise for the error path).